# I am getting an error "Failed to load org.apache.spark.examples"

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting this error, how can I run these Spark jobs (in Scala)?

Command:

```
bin/run-example /home/datadotz/streaming/wc_str.scala localhost 9999
```

Error:

```
Failed to load org.apache.spark.examples./home/datadotz/streami
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.examples.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the documentation -- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/#running-the-examples-and-shell

> To run one of the Java or Scala sample programs, use bin/run-example  [params] in the top-level Spark directory

It also mentions you can use `spark-submit` to run programs, which seems to take a path. Try that script instead.

Comment: Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/home/xxx/streaming/wc_str.scala"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Comment: Code:object Wordcount  {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
 
 //Create conf object
 val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("WordCount")
 //create streaming context object
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
 val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
 val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(' '))
 val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
 val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)

 wordCounts.print()